# Bash writing output to file with using timeout results in error

Tags: bash

Im using this script to monitor iBeacon bluetooth devices and it works as expected.

```
sudo beacon scan -c
```

However i recently changed it to just run for a few seconds and output the result to a file like so:

```
sudo timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt
```

Problem is that this outputs nothing to there is probably an error in the command. Also writing error stream to the file gives me an error.

```
sudo timeout 5 beacon scan -c &> result.txt
```

Contents of result.txt:

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

It feels like bash is trying to apply `&> result.txt` as parameters to the `beacon scan` command. Im not very good at bash so there is probably a simple solution to this problem but i haven't found one!

Comment: Does `sudo timeout 5 beacon scan -c -- &> result.txt` work?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist nope, same result.

Comment: Two options: `sudo -s 'timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt'` or `sudo bash -c 'timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt'`. The issue being your `sudo` applies to the `timeout` command, but the redirection is performed as the normal user. Using either of the options above should do it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this did not work either, tried both ways:
`pi@pibeacon ~ $ sudo -s 'timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt'
/bin/bash: timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt: command not found
pi@pibeacon ~ $ sudo bash -c 'timeout 5 beacon scan -c > result.txt'
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error`

Comment: the timeout doesn't need to be sudo'ed. Try `timout 5 sudo beacon scan -c > result.txt`

Comment: @Richard - Grr.. sorry, I have run into the `sudo` redirection issues so often that are solved with either of those options, I overlooked the `timeout` behavior. Hopefully ccarton has it correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin running  `timeout 5 sudo beacon scan -c > result.txt` will output to the text file but does not timeout :/

Comment: tried with `timeout -k 5s 4s sudo beacon scan -c &> result.txt
` but then i just got the error message in the result.txt file

Comment: Well, as a random shot in the dark, maybe the beacon command doesn't like the TERM signal for some reason. You can try the `-s INT` option to have timeout send SIGINT instead.

Comment: @ccarton it worked! awesome, final script was:
`sudo bash -c 'timeout -s INT 2s beacon scan -c > result.txt`

Comment: @ccarton write the comment as an answer here and i will accept and you'll get your rep! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs designed to be interrupted with ctrl-c don't behave the same when terminated with sigterm, which is what timeout will send by default. Try using the option `-s INT` to have timeout send sigint instead.